# ¿Es correcto utilizar "amparadme" de esta forma?

Tags: conjugación, concordancia-gramatical

Junto a una imagen de la Virgen en Buenos Aires estaba la siguiente inscripción:
[image: Oh María Madre Mía Virgencita de Luján Amparadme y Guiadme a la Patria Celestial]

Si el sujeto es María, ¿no debería decir "ampárame y guíame"?
¿El sujeto no es María? ¿esta forma aparentemente plural puede usarse en singular en este contexto? ¿Era así en otra época?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero veamos de donde viene.

> Amparadme: Forma **enclítica** del Singular del modo Imperativo del
> verbo amparar

El significado de amparar se refiere a valerse del favor de alguno.
En este caso, Él pide que lo ampare, pero utiliza un recurso llamado el **Voseo**
que como mencionaron anteriormente es solo una forma arcaica de como referirse a alguien con mucho respeto o dirigirse a una alta autoridad, antiguamente así se referían los sirvientes o mayordomos a su ''Amo o Señora''

El caso de '**Amparadme y Guiadme**' utilizan este '**Voseo**'.
Pero, ¿Qué es el voceo realmente?

> voseo es un fenómeno lingüístico dentro de la lengua española en el
> que se emplea el pronombre «vos» junto a ciertas conjugaciones
> verbales particulares para dirigirse al interlocutor en lugar de
> emplear el pronombre «tú» en situaciones de familiaridad.

Actualmente el **Voseo** ya no se habla, solo se usa como recurso literario para escribir poesía y el **ustedeo** es el usado para referirse a alguien con respeto *(Pero este es otro tema)*

Así que, respondiendo tu pregunta, sí, es correcto usar el 'Amparadme' de esa forma, porque esta refiriéndose con respecto a 'La Virgencita de Lujan' que es considerada como una autoridad

Espero haberte ayudado, *good luck*

Answer (score 4):

Es un ejemplo de [plural mayestático](https://blog.lengua-e.com/2011/plural-mayestatico/), una forma arcaica de dirigirse a una alta autoridad, o de que dicha autoridad hable de sí misma.

Ese mismo ejemplo forma parte de una [conocida canción tradicional](https://funjdiaz.net/a_canciones2.php?id=42).

Answer (score 2):

Actualmente esa forma no aparece recogida en el DLE en la conjugación del verbo [amparar](https://dle.rae.es/amparar) pero a mí no me parece que sea incorrecta, solo **arcaica**. Es de cuando se empleaba el pronombre vos como indicativo de **respeto**.

> Amparadme vos

Algo sobre la [evolución del voseo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo) puede consultarse en la Wikipedia.

No encuentro ahora mismo fotos pero en una fachada de una de las iglesias de mi ciudad (Málaga, España) creo que también podría encontrar esa forma verbal para dirigirse a la Virgen o a Dios. La iglesia en cuestión no es antigua, es de finales del siglo XX.

Creo que en ese ámbito católico se sigue usando actualmente con ese doble motivo, al tener un matiz arcaico se resalta la antigüedad de la Iglesia Católica y de la biblia, por un lado, y al tener un matiz de respeto, se resalta la adoración a esas figuras y la distancia entre ellas y los meros pecadores mortales.

Comment: Los verbos que terminan en ar, tienen el imperativo plural: ad: Cantad ahora! Así que amparad. Vosotros. Como: Vuestra Majestad, amparadme en mis navegaciones en el nuevo mundo –